# Flame color vs electrical discharge color

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry

I don't know the right terms to frame the question but here it goes:

Neon and argon give their characteristic colors when a current is passed through them at low pressure.  Balmer series etc, I understand what's going on there.

Other compounds like boron will give a nice green in a flame test.  Boron in alcohol for example.  But in an electrical discharge, nothing happens.
I'm not understanding where the difference is in the manner of exciting the boron atoms.

How can I find a compound that will give a strong green color with an electrical discharge, at low pressure (1 torr)?

Comment: I don't know if you could produce atomic oxygen in your system, but this article may (or probably may not) give you some ideas along those lines: http://www.ann-geophys.net/30/695/2012/angeo-30-695-2012.pdf

Comment: It would be a sealed tube like a neon light.   I thought of Oxygen, but I don't think it would be a good idea, my only way to get the low pressure is with a vacuum pump.  Oil, oxygen. :(  Seems risky.

Comment: There are certainly pumps available that would be safe, but you know your equipment and yea, don't go there if that could be an issue, :( indeed.

Comment: Boron is not a gas. Related http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/53281/compound-with-a-bright-green-emission-when-electrically-excited

Comment: Boron compounds can be.

Comment: Here is an interesting interactive site that gives the emission spectra for eight different elements.  None of them would give you a pure green without filtering other emission wavelengths, say with a coating on your tube.  Neon has good emission in the green range for example but the red is so intense I doubt you could filter it out and have any significant green left.  Anyway, here's the site: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/atspect2.html#c1

Comment: @user103218 That's why trimethyl borate colors the flame green. It brings boron atoms to the gas phase where they can be excited and emit green light. However, this is impractical in a gas discharge tube.

Comment: Ok, why is trimethyl borate impractical?   I haven't gotten it to work yet.  I don't think it matters how the electrons get excited, and slamming high voltage current through them seems like it ought to be working.

Comment: I think trimethyl borate will be unstable under the harsh conditions in a gas discharge tube.

Comment: Ok, so how do I go about finding a compound that is a gas at around 1 torr, which will give me a bright green emission line without much else, when electrically excited?